# centering block of images on all screen sizes bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to center a block of social icons underneath h1 text on all screen sizes. I almost got it, there are just 2 sizes where it keeps shifting.

[Here is how it looks where it is shifted to the left slightly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMmZc.png)

[here it's shifted to the right slightly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1peYt.png)

Here is my code:

```
<div id="container">

        <div class="social-and-coming">
    <div class="coming-soon text-center ">
        <h1 class="coming ">Coming Soon</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <ul class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-11 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-11 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-11">

        <li class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1"><a href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/avaziomedia/Facebook.png" alt=""></a></li> 
        <li class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1"><a href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/avaziomedia/Twitter.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1"><a href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/avaziomedia/Instagram.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1"><a href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/avaziomedia/Youtube.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1"><a href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/avaziomedia/pinterest.png" alt=""></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my css:

```
#container{
      // min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}

.site-title a{
    font-family: Heiti TC;
    color: #E8970C;
}

.text-center{
    color: #E8970C;
}

.coming-soon h1{
    font-family: Heiti TC;
    font-size: 75px;
}

.row{
    // width:700px;
margin: 0px auto;
}

.col-xs-1{
    margin-left: 15px;
}



li{
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

img{
    width:40px;
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the list and use `text-center` like you did for the title, it should work:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="social-and-coming">
        <div class="coming-soon text-center">
            <h1 class="coming">Coming Soon</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <a href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/avaziomedia/Facebook.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/avaziomedia/Twitter.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/avaziomedia/Instagram.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/avaziomedia/Youtube.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/avaziomedia/pinterest.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using some bootstrap offsets and so it will never be in the middle. I would suggest simplifying this and getting rid of the UL classes and add an `id` to it which applies the following CSS:

```
#socialLinks {
  list-style:none;
  text-align: center;
}

#socialLinks li {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

---

**[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/qfrc72e5/)**

```css
#container {
  // min-height:100%;
  position: relative;
}

.site-title a {
  font-family: Heiti TC;
  color: #E8970C;
}

.text-center {
  color: #E8970C;
}

.coming-soon h1 {
  font-family: Heiti TC;
  font-size: 75px;
}

.row {
  // width:700px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.col-xs-1 {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

li {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

img {
  width: 40px;
}

#socialLinks {
  list-style:none;
  text-align: center;
}

#socialLinks li {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="container">

  <div class="social-and-coming">
    <div class="coming-soon text-center ">
      <h1 class="coming ">Coming Soon</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <ul id="socialLinks">

        <li class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <a href=""><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""></a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <a href=""><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""></a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <a href=""><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""></a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <a href=""><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""></a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <a href=""><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy:

```
.yourclass {
    width: SPECIFY_WIDTH;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

It will always center irresepctive of any screen size. If you want spacing around on small devices then add padding to `class`.

Comment: would .yourclass just be wrapped around the ul element in a div?

Comment: you can add wherever you want, but that element should be `block` or `inline-block`. 
I would recommend you `ul`

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use Bootstraps Div class helpers?

class: Text-center (text)
Class: center-block (images)

They seem to work for me, i dont do offsets much so not 100% how effective they will be.